# javascript: Sourcing defaults for one json object from another - handling arrays in different sort order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am receiving a json as parameter and I also have a template base json. I need to check that all objects of the template json should are present in the tgt json and if not, need to initialize those variables with template json.

Following is my implementation.

```
var jsonBase = {  
  "Et":"Val_Retain",
  "A1": {    
      "A12": {
          "A12Array": [              
            {
                  "key1": "val1"
            },
            {
                 "key2": "val2"                   
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }

var jsonTgt = {  
  "Et":"OldVal",
  "A1": {    
      "A12": {
          "A12Array": [              
            {
                  "key1": "val1Old_Retain"
            }            
          ]
        }
      }
    }

initKeys(jsonBase,jsonTgt)
function initKeys(obj,tgt) {   
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(element, key, _array) {        
        var cur;        

        if (typeof(tgt[element])=="undefined") {            
            tgt[element]=obj[element]
        }
        if (typeof(obj[element])=="object") {
                initKeys(obj[element],tgt[element])
        }
    })    
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonTgt))
```

The output is:

```
{
    "Et": "OldVal",
    "A1": {
        "A12": {
            "A12Array": [{
                    "key1": "val1Old_Retain"
                }, {
                    "key2": "val2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

There are two questions:

- Is this correct approach or there could be a more efficient or a
  simpler one with available js/nodejs libs?
- **More Importantly** - What do I do in case if the array sort order doesn't match with template as below.

Changed sort order

```
var json2 = {  
  "Et":"OldVal",
  "A1": {    
      "A12": {
          "A12Array": [              
            {
                  "key2": "val1Old_Retain"
            }            
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

The above produces the following output:

```
{
    "Et": "OldVal",
    "A1": {
        "A12": {
            "A12Array": [{
                    "key2": "val1Old_Retain",
                    "key1": "val1"
                }, {
                    "key2": "val2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

as against the desired:

```
{
    "Et": "OldVal",
    "A1": {
        "A12": {
            "A12Array": [{                  
                    "key1": "val1"
                }, {
                    "key2": "val1Old_Retain"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understood expected output. Why it should remove `key2` from 1st element, and retain its value in 2nd element of the array?

Comment: So, my keys would be unique across the arrays and if key1 is missing in the target json that needs to be filled in with template values, instead of adding a new item with it will append the first item with key1's value from template and create a separate element with key2 from template. This could be a custom rqmt but i want this to be generically implemented in my module.

Comment: Can there be many levels of nesting, or is it always the same level of nesting i.e. collection inside object xy inside object x?

Comment: @Amine - no nesting level will be fixed for the template

Comment: why do u need a12array inside of a12, why not just use 12 as an array..?

Comment: Thats just how the template is designed by the third party

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the first sample code I have been able to make and it works, however, I think that the way you implemented your code is wrong since I am pretty sure you could have done something much simpler if you had in mind functional programming methods i.e. [those native methods from mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array), and [those ones from lodash library](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) don't forget to mark as answered if I did, otherwise please comment so I get more information about your exact situation

```
var _ = require('lodash')
let jsonInput = {
    "Et": "Val_Retain",
    "A1": {
        "A12": {
            "A12Array": [{
                "key1": "val1"
            }, {
                "key2": "val2"
            }]
        }
    }
}

let jsonInput2 = {
    "Et": "OldVal",
    "A1": {
        "A12": {
            "A12Array": [{
                "key1": "val1Old_Retain"
            }]
        }
    }
}

for (let key1 in jsonInput) {
    if (key1 === 'Et') {
        jsonInput[key1] = "OldVal"
    } else {
        for (let key2 in jsonInput[key1]) {
            for (let key3 in jsonInput[key1][key2]) {
                console.log(jsonInput[key1][key2][key3])
                let listOfKeys = getKeys(jsonInput[key1][key2][key3])
                console.log(listOfKeys)
                console.log(jsonInput2[key1][key2])
                console.log(key3)
                let listOfKeys2 = getKeys(jsonInput2[key1][key2][key3])
                console.log(listOfKeys2)
                let uniqkeys = _.uniq(listOfKeys.concat(listOfKeys2))
                let sortedUniqkeys = _.sortBy(uniqkeys)
                let result = []
                console.log('sortedUniqkeys', sortedUniqkeys)
                sortedUniqkeys.forEach((key4, i) => {
                    let doc = {}
                    if (listOfKeys2.indexOf(key4) != -1) {
                        jsonInput2[key1][key2][key3].forEach((e, i) => {
                            if (e[key4]) {
                                doc[key4] = e[key4]
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        jsonInput[key1][key2][key3].forEach((e, i) => {
                            if (e[key4]) {
                                doc[key4] = e[key4]
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    result.push(doc)
                    console.log(key4, jsonInput[key1][key2][key3][key4])
                    console.log(result)
                })
                jsonInput[key1][key2][key3] = result
            }
        }
    }
}

function getKeys(arr) {
    console.log(arr)
    return arr.reduce(function(accumulator, value, index, array) {
        for (let key3 in value) {
            accumulator.push(key3)
        }
        return accumulator
    }, []);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonInput))
```